# How to read ICollection from Model in MVC 5

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, tuples

I need to read Icollection from Model in View. I have this situation.

I have 3 classes: Alternative, Question and QuestionAlternative

Class

```
namespace Models
{
public class QuestionAlternative
{

    public int QuestionAlternativeID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int AlternativeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Alternative> Alternative { get; set; }

 }
}
```

Question

```
namespace Models
{
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public int FactorID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Complement { get; set; }
    public int IndexOrder { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }

    public virtual Factor Factor { get; set; }

     }
    }
```

Alternative

```
namespace Models
{
public class Alternative
{        
    public int AlternativeID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
    public int IndexOrder { get; set; }
     }
    }
```

My Controller

```
namespace Inventario.Controllers
{

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private InventarioContext db = new InventarioContext();
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Questionnaire()
    {          
        var questionAlternative = db.QuestionAlternatives.Include(qa => qa.Question).Include(qa => qa.Alternative);
        return View("../Equipment/Questionnaire", questionAlternative);
    }
}
```

}

My View

```
<div class="table-responsive">
@using (Html.BeginForm("getRadioValues", "Equipment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nº</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var question in Model.GroupBy(q=>q.Question))
            {
                <tr>

                    <td width="10px"><b>@question.Key.QuestionID - @question.Key.Description</b> </td>
                </tr>
                foreach (var alternative in question)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.RadioButton("radio" + @question.Key.QuestionID, alternative.QuestionAlternativeID, false)@alternative.Alternative.HOW TO ACCESS THE FIELDS OS <Alternatives> LIST
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="submit" />
    }

   </div>
```

In my view I grouped All alternatives for each question. I need to access the properties of the Alternative class to print the alternatives, but it is a collection in my model . How to do it? How to access public virtual ICollection Alternative { get; set; } inside model

Comment: Your creating radio buttons which have no relationship to your models so this wont post back to you model! You need to re think this and create view models to display/edit what you you need and bind to a model on post back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually access it exactly how you wrote: `@alternative.Alternative`. It is a collection (you mentioned it correctly), so you can just access by index or enumerate through it.+